# Elasticsearch snapshot backups in azure repository unknown host exception

Tags: azure, elasticsearch, yaml, azure-storage

Trying to create backup repository for snapshots in Elasticsearch 6.5.2. But I am getting Internal server error(500) when executing the curl below. The error message is `{"type":"unknown_host_exception","reason":"{{storage-account-name}}.blob.core.windows.net"}`  I checked multiple times and this storage account exists in azure, as well as the container and the key matches. The storage account lives inside a different resource group than the resource group of the elasticsearch cluster. However, I do not think this is the issue.

```
 curl -X PUT http://{{address}}/_snapshot/{{repo-name}} \
        -H 'Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8' -v \
        -d '{
        "type": "azure",
            "settings": {
                "container": "{{container-name}}",
                "chunk_size": "32m",
                "compress": true
            }
        }'
```

My elasticsearch.yml has the following configuration:

```
cloud.azure.storage.timeout: 10s
azure.client.default.max_retries: 7
azure.client.default.endpoint_suffix: {{azure-cloud}}

cloud:
    azure:
        storage:
            {{container-name}}:
                account: {{storage-account-name}}
                key:{{storage-account-key}}
```

Comment: Looks to me like your variable `storage-account-name` is not being properly replaced. How did you define it?

Comment: All of the {{XXX}} are actually real names in my code. I just did not want to reveal the actual names. You can consider these as actual names that match between the yml file and the curl request.

Comment: It seems that you're missing a space between key and the variable, but I'm not sure if this is the reason